# formatting .csv to json in python for individual key:value pairs

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying format individual key:value pairs from a csv document to JSON and using json.dump(). While it seems to be working well for the most part, it is turning my integers into strings(or perhaps I need to turn my strings into integers, depending on which way it's looked at), which i do not want, and I also need one key:value pair to become a JSON array.

my code is basically this at the moment:

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('spreadsheet.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('fileTo.json', 'w') 

fieldnames = ("Id","name","TypeId","Type", "listHere")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)

for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ':'))
    jsonfile.write(',')
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

where I need Id and TypeId to be integers, and listHere to become a JSON array.

currently the output is as such:

```
[
    {
        "name":"someName",
        "Id":"1",
        "Type":"someType",
        "TypeId":"2",
        "listHere":"someList"
    },
]
```

Where what I need is:

```
 [
    {
        "name":"someName",
        "Id":1,
        "Type":"someType",
        "TypeId":2,
        "listHere":
        [
             "someList"
        ]       
    },
]
```

I read through the docs, but do not really see how to do it with a spreadsheet that has thousands of entries in it.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When you read items with the csv module, they're always presented as string values.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that, it was kinda what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csv` doesn't support column types, although that would be nice.

The following code (untested) has a "fixer" function for some fields. Before each row is translated into JSON, some fields' values are translated using a fixer function.  `int(field)` in this case.

**Note:** although each row is output as JSON, the entire list is not.  Currently it has a trailing ",".  Considering using [json.iterencode()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.iterencode) to "stream" the data to a JSON file.

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('spreadsheet.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('fileTo.json', 'w') 

fieldnames = ("Id","name","TypeId","Type", "listHere")
fieldfixers = {
    'Id': int,
    'Type': int,
}
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)

for row in reader:
    for key,value in row.iteritems():
        ffunc = fieldfixers.get(key)
        if ffunc:
            row[key] = ffunc(value)
    json.dump(row, jsonfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ':'))
    jsonfile.write(',')
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the input, that took care of the integer problem.  Any trick converting the "listHere" to the JSON array?

Comment: @shavenwarthog you can make it a little cleaner with a `defaultdict`, as at [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zTsHqptA).  I'm not posting a separate answer because it's just a cleanup.  (Note that I omitted the fieldnames/other ceremony at the top.)

Comment: Thanks for the alternative method @syrion.  I'm pretty fresh to python so still learning all the tricks.  Also, I still can't figure out how to make my last field so that it shows up as a JSON array...

Comment: @v3rbal If your final column is a list in a single field--let's say a list of integers separated by commas, appearing in the csv as `"1,2,3"`--you can simply make a transformer function for it as well.  In my pastebin, you could add `'listHere': lambda x: map(int, x.split(','))` to the dictionary parameter of the `update` call.

Comment: Ah, thanks again @syrion, I can see how this will work. Very much appreciated.